# Change the line spacing inside the long free translation (gb4e)

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, cgloss4e, translations

I'm currently using gb4e package for my glossed examples. Their translations are sometimes quite long (more than one line). Since the paragraphs before and after have been defined \linespread{1.5}, so the paragraphs of the example translation also have the same spacing. Is there anyway to change the spacing of the translations (globally, since all long examples have the same issues)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex ``Who should I talk to if I want to get a recommendation letter?''
\begin{xlist}
\ex
\gll Cong yiyue dao liuyue, dou shi Wang laoshi fuze xie tuijianxin. Qiyue dao shi'eryue shi cai laoshi fuze xie tuijianxin.\\
from Janarary until June all {\small{COP}} Wang teacher in.charge.of write recommendation.letter July until December {\small{COP}} Cai teacher in.charge.of write recommendation.letter\\

`From Janarary until June teacher Wang is in charge of writing recommendation letter. On July until December, teacher Cai is in charge of writing recommendation letter. ' 


\end{xlist}
\end{exe}


\end{document}
```

In other words, for these two sentences,`From Janarary until June teacher Wang is in charge of writing recommendation letter. On July until December, teacher Cai is in charge of writing recommendation letter,' I hope to have same line spacing as the first two glossed line.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you want to change the document line spacing it's better to use the `setspace` package do do so. This will give you commands that can be used inside environments to go back to singlespacing when needed. Also, the free translation in `gb4e` should be introduced with `\glt` (or `\trans`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex ``Who should I talk to if I want to get a recommendation letter?''
\begin{xlist}
\ex
\gll Cong yiyue dao liuyue, dou shi Wang laoshi fuze xie tuijianxin. Qiyue dao shi'eryue shi cai laoshi fuze xie tuijianxin.\\
from Janarary until June all {\small{COP}} Wang teacher in.charge.of write recommendation.letter July until December {\small{COP}} Cai teacher in.charge.of write recommendation.letter\\

\glt\singlespacing`From Janarary until June teacher Wang is in charge of writing recommendation letter. On July until December, teacher Cai is in charge of writing recommendation letter. ' 


\end{xlist}
\end{exe}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]